# Copy wordpress settings to another blog

Tags: configuration

I need to set up many blogs, which all have to look the same, with the default wordpress theme.

I still need to adjust a lot: removing some sites, changing language etc.

I need like 30 min for everything, but I need to do it everytime.

Is there a way to copy my configuration, so when I upload the WP zip to my webspace and unzip it, all my configurations are saved.

I tryed downloading an existing WP folder, which is configurated and uploading it to a new site, but it didnt kept the configuration.

It simpy, skiped the database creation, because there was already a config.php.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ may help. Copying files will not create a new database. You must create the database through another means - such as your host's Cpanel or whatever db management software they have - and edit wp-config.php to insert the new db's credentials.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit too unspecific, but generally all the configuration is in the database so you need to clone that.

Generally for automating things you should have a look at [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) if you feel comfortable working on the command line.